# Uncertain of 8-bit vs 32-bit alternatives to AVR32

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, avr

I was browsing a distributor to find options for simple 8-bit and 32-bit RISC uCs and came across AVR32. After some searching on the web, it seems that AVR32 is a bit dated and possibly not a good choice for long term sustainability. (I am unfamiliar with what’s popular in 2021)

As someone with limited experience, mostly in C with Arduino development kits, what alternatives exist to AVR for 8-bit and 32-bit that are 1) not near end-of-production life cycle 2) have strong support via communities & examples and 3) do not require an OS? (not looking for a microprocessor)

Context: I am eventually looking to design a custom PCB for my project. Also, my project is a simple feedback loop that uses some basic sensors and a motor... I believe a microprocessor is certainly an overkill for my project in terms of infrastructure and cost, so I am specifically seeking microcontrollers.

Comment: You didn’t stumble across ARM based micros in your search? There’s plenty of choices for boards/devices supported by Arduino. I’m working with a Teensy 4.1 at the moment for example.

Comment: This is too opinion-based and answers will be dated which means the question will be closed. But I do sympathize with the situation the OP is. I will say that STM32 is fairly user friendly (at least the STM32F3 and likely the STM32F0 as well). Higher variants like the STM32F7 or STM32H7 are much more powerful but also get much more convoluted, even if you have experience with the simpler ones. And have cheap compilers in the form of Rowley Crossworks and Segger IDE (which is just a white-labelled rebrand of the former). And they are free for personal use but also have a cheap personal license.

Comment: Bryan, if you are trying to avoid instruction sets and architectures that are "a bit dated," then RISC-V is where the world is going. It's an entirely modern design and open to all. [Here's a block diagram and simulator](http://x.dii.unisi.it:8098/~giorgi/WebRISC-V/index.php) for a couple of instantiations that's available as a web page you can play with. But, for example, MIPS is now fully dedicated to RISC-V and all of Samsung's future drives will be based upon it. Etc. It's where things are at. There are announcements every single day with large and small companies shifting over.

Comment: @Kartman I’ve only looked at ARM briefly. If I remember correctly, some of those needed a Linux setup? My project is far too simple to need so much system infrastructure.

Comment: @jonk and DKNguyen thank you. I should have phrased my question in terms of what’s popular today and not near a “end-of-life” state.

Comment: @BryanA. Well, you can still get not only old designs but entirely brand new designs on new FAB processes for the ancient 6502 from Western Digital. I worked on one not so long back, in fact. That ancient beast isn't "end of life" even now. There are many ancient cores that will be around still for decades yet. If all you are looking for is "well vetted and lots of tools and lots and lots of software examples and lots of people familiar with it" then anything related to ARM is that. But popularity varies by the year, too. Best wishes, regardless.

Comment: The ARM Cortex M0/3/4/7/22/33 are microcontrollers. You can run them bare metal or with an RTOS like freertos. Arduino has support for many of them. Looks at the list of boards in the IDE to guide you.  Cortex A series are the ones you run Linux on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVR is popular because of Arduino. The AVR32, considerably less so, and there are variants of it going end-of-life. It would not be a good investment, given better-supported options out there.

The most popular 32-bit devices are ARM-based, which would include:

- STM32 (ST Micro - huge range of choices)
- i.MX6 / MX8 family (NXP, also very extensive range)
- BCM2837 (Broadcom, used on Raspberry Pi)
- Rockchip RK3399

As well as Allwinner, etc. Some of the boards using these adopt Arduino-like footprints to address that mindshare and take advantage of that ecosystem. Others knock off Raspberry Pi (e.g., OrangePi, which uses Rockchip.)

Another popular platform is ESP32 from ExpressIF, which uses a Tensilica core. It's very low cost and includes wifi.

I'm basing this on the number of questions that seem to come up here. I'm leaving out dozens of others, notably MIPS (very old, but still used in a lot of wifi routers, sorry @jonk) and Risc-V types (still kind of new, not popular outside of China yet.)

Comment: Also Atmel SAM-D range is worth a look

Comment: @Frog I’ve seen it around a bit, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @hacktastical Out of all of those that you’ve listed, if your program was a simple feedback loop with maybe a few basic sensors/motors/etc that only needed I2C/SPI/UART peripherals (maybe BlueTooth, as a bonus), which options would you lean toward? .. coming from a background using Arduino.

Comment: All are within reach of even the ATMega that's on the basic Arduino, except if you need very fancy motor control (like, multi-phase H-bridge drivers and such.) Renesas, TI and ST have specialty ICs for those that include some DSP capability.

Comment: If you’re comfortable with the Arduino IDE then ESP32 is directly supported, also SAM3X (for the Arduino Due), and quite possibly many others but I don’t have the IDE in front of me.  SAM3X is a little old-fashioned these days but could be a good option if you need lots of IO pins.  Changing to a new IDE is never trivial and Arduino is quite easy to use.