# How to determine which connectivity and peripherals are needed in a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, design, peripheral

This post goes a step beyond my previous question about microcontroller selection [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554982/uncertain-of-8-bit-vs-32-bit-alternatives-to-avr32). In short, I am a moving away from AVR for product development and I want to stick with popular manufacturer uC series that have longevity and a lot of community support around them for troubleshooting.

In this process, I am having some confusion with uC selection based on required connectivity and peripherals. I know that I will need some combination of I2C, SPI and UART connectivity. Also, I know that I will need PWM and timer peripherals. In my current prototype, I have an external Bluetooth module, LCD (OLED), and motor controller. Unfortunately, when I include Bluetooth and LCD as necessary peripherals in my searching, I notice that 1) either the selections to choose from become a lot more limited or 2) often a lot of other peripherals and supporting connectivity are required with the additions.

1. In industry, do developers generally try to simplify things by including as many peripherals as possible in their uC selection (if cost effective), even if it's an overkill in the sense of potentially adding more uC capability than what may be needed?
2. Aside from my soft requirement to work with a well supported and popular series, is it more a matter of the cost driving whether to choose a uC with all the needed connectivity/peripherals and then some?

Comment: Most likely when you click LCD support, it means that the MCU has to have a LCD interface. Which you don't need if your OLED has I2C or SPI. You need to be sure what interface your devices have and what do you need from the MCU to interface it.

Comment: Of key note is you actually want to check the more complex peripherals like Bluetooth and LCD in the manual to see if you are actually able to use them and if they are actually applicable for the hardware you want to use.

Comment: If your external bluetooth module uses a serial bus to interface to the uc, then you don't need a microcontroller with bluetooth. Not clear to me what your actual needs are.

Comment: Here's a rundown of the low end of the market:
https://jaycarlson.net/microcontrollers/

Comment: Typically in the industries I've worked in, "adding more uC capability than what may be needed" is not a problem - it's not even a 'thing'. What is a 'thing' is "adding more uC *cost* than what may be *allowed by the budget*". Figure out what is affordable and for the initial prototypes, get as many bells and whistles as will fit - then once your firmware is "complete" you can consider paring it down to a cheaper part to save money and increase profit.

Answer (score 3):

> In industry, do developers generally try to simplify things ... even if it's an overkill in the sense of potentially adding more uC capability ...

Why do you care if the microprocessor is "too capable"?  You care that it's capable enough, then you care about the lifetime cost of the product (to oversimplify: engineering time / number of boards + cost per board)

> is it more a matter of the cost driving whether to choose a uC

In general it should be, but you need to be careful that you account for all the costs.  If you're saving $0.10 per board in bill of materials cost, but you spend $100 per board more on engineering costs, then you've lost money on that decision.

> Unfortunately, when I include Bluetooth and LCD as necessary peripherals in my searching...

Those are pretty specialized items, so it's not a surprise that they narrow your choices.

In your shoes, I would assess the total cost of a board with all that stuff on the micro, and the cost with everything but that on the micro and those two separate.

You should also be aware that if you just put a Bluetooth module on your board then the module comes with all the necessary certifications with the Bluetooth marketing association (or whatever its correct name is), as well as FCC certification.

As soon as you step away from a module, you're on your own for getting that board certified.  That's a huge expense if it's only amortized over 1000 boards or so (and ever much more so if it's only amortized over 10).  There's definitely a tipping point where it makes sense to build the board with some Bluetooth device rather than a module -- but I think you'll find it's north of anything a sole proprietor business is going to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

> In industry, do developers generally try to simplify things by
> including as many peripherals as possible in their uC selection (if
> cost effective), even if it's an overkill in the sense of potentially
> adding more uC capability than what may be needed?

Generally no, Like it depends on what you want to achieve. For example if someone is making large volume product, then every buck matters, so sometime they end up with a very small uC and they implement functionality such as I2C (for example) etc, on their own in that uC. However, in areas where cost doesn't matter but the time to build product matter more (like the place where custom make products are made), there you can expect one beefy uC doing just one small task.

These days, people are using MCU with RTOS on it, it makes development and maintenance fast and less expensive.

As you have written that you are moving away from AVR to "popular uC manufacturer"  always see if that MCU supports some RTOS. Other than that see if manufacturer provides HAL/LL for the MCU that you selects because as the MCU becomes more complex, it really becomes tedious and un productive to configure MCU on register level. I have worked mostly on STM32 MCU and they have good HAL/LL support, however, MCU from TI and NXP are also good.

To see if the MCU supports the some RTOS, then first select the RTOS you want to work with there are many but start with FreeRTOS as it is Free. Then go to the devices support and see if the MCU you want to work with or its architecture has been mentioned there.

---

Don't search for MCU with LCD(I am Assuming a simple 16x2 type LCD) support because you can drive it with I2C using PCF8574 or even directly from GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on microcontrollers for 25 years now.

Use ARM core microcontrollers.

NXP's microcontrollers have a very few hardware bugs.

ST's microcontrollers have more bugs but are cheaper

Renesas is the best but every once in a while there's shortage.

To answer your questions:

Usually people don't pick the microcontroller that has the broadest number of peripherals. That's overkilling the application.

Cost always matters.

I personally pick the one that doesn't go obsolete soon and the one that has the minimum requirements to suite my needs.

Comment: Enrico, got any hard evidence to support your claims? ST really has more bugs than NXP and Renesas is the 'best'?

Comment: @EnricoMigliore thanks for the info! I'm interested in STM, as I see it around the web quite often. As Kartman said, do you have a reference to this or some example?

Comment: @BryanA.: I design ultr-low power products therefore I pick my microcontrollers here: https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-ultra-low-power-mcus.html

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, you select an MCU that can do what it should depending on many criteria. Sometimes it is the MCU price, but sometimes how fast you can develop it, as time and work to devlop hardware and software also costs money. You do your best to estimate what peripherals you need, how many of them you need, and how fast MCU you need, how many IO pins you need, how much Flash memory and SRAM you need. Sometimes these are somewhat unknown and sometimes you need to have reserve for future updates and features.

Usually it is a compromise anyway, as you can't have an MCU which exactly fits your requirements directly, if you need lots of memory, or certain set of peripherals, it usually means the package is larger and you have more IO than you need.

2. No, as I mentioned in 1, it is what you value most and where to put the money. For example if you want to have as cheap MCU as possible since you make a lot of devices, you have to spend a lot of time carefully evaluating your options. Perhaps even buy an expensive commercial compiler and expensive debugger and programmer to develop tight code quickly. But for a one-off product, it does not matter much of the MCU costs 10 or 20 USD/EUR, and you might want a MCU that has free compiler and cheap debugger, which maybe comes with a 20 USD/EUR eval board.